# store.js working inconsistently (not quite cross-browser incompatible, but similar)

Tags: javascript

Background: I'm trying to track if users who submit a contact form are from google Adwords. I'm using store.js to track whether the user has come from adwords, and then just noting in the email whether the user is from Adwords or not. (Note: I don't care what Adwords campaign they clicked on, at this time - I just want to know if they clicked on one at all.)

This worked fine on localhost, and it's working fine for me on the production site (tested on both Chrome and Firefox). However, it's not working on my coworker's Chrome (but it does work for her Safari).

Pretty simple: check the url, if it's got "?gclid", then set the keyword via store.js. From there, if keyword exists, put a note in the email that says "yep, keyword exists".

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("?gclid") > -1) {
    var searchItem = window.location.search.replace("?gclid=",""); 
    store.set('keyword', searchItem); 
}; 

var keyword = store.get('keyword');
```

One other thing: In Chrome, I can check the keyword storage in the console, using store.get(keyword). In Mozilla, it returns keyword as undefined (but if I add "console.log(keyword);" the keyword shows up).

Any ideas as to why this would work inconsistently? Something obvious that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, had a similar problem with this in the past -- And (not proudly) I had to "work around" it  --  This is just a suggestion, but I handled it with a small `AJAX` call and stored the info I needed in `php's` `$_SESSION`.  That way I am guaranteed the correct info is stored regardless of browser / server configuration.  The problem with that, of course is, you have to have another `AJAX` call to retrieve said info.   I am interested in this question, and hope you get the answer you're looking for ... Good luck!